# How to use ReactiveCocoa to sendKeypath when the type of return value is CGFloat

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

```
       self.subscription = [[[RACObserve(photoModel, fullsizedData) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
                return value != nil;
          }]map:^id(id value) {
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    } ]setKeyPath:@keypath(self.imageView.layer,borderWidth)onObject:self.imageView];
```

error log is:

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
   reason: '[<UIImageView 0x7b1a8510> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cornerRadius.
```

and i think if there is another way to react the value who's type is float,int and so on .i will accept it

Comment: Shouldn't it be @keypath(self.imageView, layer.borderWidth) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use string instead of a `@keypath` macro.

```
    [... setKeyPath:"layer.borderWidth" onObject:self.imageView];
```

Or you can use the RAC macro which is much clearer.

```
    RAC(self.imageView, layer.borderWidth)
    = [[RACObserve(photoModel, fullsizedData) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return value != nil;
    }] map:^id(id value) {
        return @1.0f;
    }];
```

Comment: You could also get rid of all the blocks, using signal operators: `[[RACObserve(photoModel, fullsizedData] ignore:nil] mapReplace:@1.0f]`